# Llamar funcion de ionic desde jquery

Tags: jquery, ionic, ionic3, ionic-framework

tengo una duda no se si es posible... lo quiero quiero hacer es desde jquery tengo unos variables que quiere enviar a una funcion de ionic 3, no se como hacerlo...
Espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: Que has intentado hasta el momento, ya realizaste alguna investigación previa a la pregunta. De paso te dejo los siguientes enlaces, para que mejores tu pregunta. 
[¿has intentado algo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/), [¿Qué has investigado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878)

Comment: Si, por algo uso este medio como ultimo recurso...

Comment: Leíste los enlaces: [¿has intentado algo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/), [¿Qué has investigado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878)